# How to edit a S3 CSV file without downloading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to edit (add a column to) a CSV file stored in S3. I managed to do this by downloading the file, editing it with bash command and re-uploading it to S3.

But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this ?

No. S3 is an **object storage solution**, not a file system. To modify objects, you download them, modify locally and re-upload.

Having said that, you can use third party tools, such as [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) which can provide "file-like" interface for you to S3, but the underlying S3 object modification does not change.

If you do it often, you can modify S3 object from **EC2 instances** instead of downloading them to your local workstation outside of AWS.